# display jquery dialog buttons vertically

Tags: button, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to display a Jquery.dialog with two buttons displayed vertically because I'm doing a mobile view.
¿How can I do it?

```
    $('#divPopUpTiempoEspera').dialog({
        minHeight: 'auto',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width:'260px',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Inicio": function() {
               //something
                $('#divPopUpTiempoEspera').dialog('close');
            },
            "Misma búsqueda": function() {
                //something
                $('#divPopUpTiempoEspera').dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```